# Start ObjectAnimator after fragment transaction

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, fragmenttransaction, objectanimator

i have this method to scroll my textview from left to right:

```
public void scrollText() {
    float startX = 0 - scrollTxt.getWidth();
    float endX = scrollTxt.getWidth();
    ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(scrollTxt, View.X, startX, endX);
    anim.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
    anim.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.RESTART);
    anim.setDuration(9000);
    anim.start();
}
```

this method and the textview are in a fragment. i add this fragment in my activity with this code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_drawer);

    MainFragment mainFragment = new MainFragment();
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.activity_main_frame, mainFragment);
    ft.commit();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_nav);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new MainNavigationListener(drawer));
}
```

i want to start animation when fragmnet added.
i put scrollText() method in fragmnet's onResume but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `scrollTxt.getWidth()`is zero in `onResume()` because your fragment view hierarchy hasn't been measured yet. As a solution, you can postpone the animation start to the next layout pass by calling `scrollTxt.post()`.

Try this:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    scrollTxt.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            scrollText();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks! it works.
but i think you forget to add **super.onResume();** .
it can cause problem for users that just copy this answer.

Answer (score 1):

scrollTxt.getWidth() returns 0, it's not measured yet in onResume()

try with:

```
    scrollTxt.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            scrollText();
        }
    });
```

in mainFragment's onViewCreated